# Connecting Blue Prism in local machine to Blue Prism Application Server in different machine

Tags: blueprism

I am not able to connect Blue Prism to Blue Prism application server in different machine. I get error as

> > The following error has occurred:
> >     The caller was not authenticated by the service.

However, I was able to connect Blue Prism to Application Server in same machine. What to do for application server and Blue Prism in different machines? Is there some change to be done in BPServer.exe.config file for allowing remote machines to connect to application server?

Comment: What user is being used to run the Blue Prism Server service?

Comment: Administrator is being used to start the Blue Prism Server service.

Comment: Is the user on the remote machine logged in as an account that's joined to a domain?

Comment: No, it's not joined to a domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default server connection mode (`WCF: SOAP with Message Encryption & Windows Authentication`) authenticates using `Windows / Active Directory`.

If the remote machine and the server are in different domains or don't share an active directory that may be the cause.

`WCF: Insecure` connection mode does not validate server identity using active directory -- try that instead.

Comment: It works now. I am able to connect to the remote server now.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue Prism Service needs to be set-up with what we call a "service account". When doing this you should be logged in as the service account, because it uses "Windows Authentication" i.e. use the credentials of the logged in account. This part I assume is working fine for you. In order to reach the App Server connection from an Interactive Client on a different box you need to set the SPN for this particular service account, which will clear this error. Follow these steps: https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-7-0/en-us/installation/bp-enterprise/SPN-configuration.htm

Reach out to the individuals that handle Active Directory at your organisation - for us they had the right level of access to run the "setspn" command.

It can also be because of the reason described above with different domains - meaning the the Active Directory is not shared - but this is less likely within one organisation.

Its similar steps to this issue that arose after a Microsoft Update in Jan 2022, described here: https://help.blueprism.com/Alerts/1784860762/Latest-on-Windows-updates-from-11th-January-2022-causing-authentication-issues-in-Blue-Prism.